# Add :class to a link

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

The documentation at https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Link.html#link/2 gives the following example to add a class to `link`:

```
link("<hello>", to: "/world", class: "btn")
```

But when I use the following code Phoenix raises an argument error:

```
<%= link "Register", to: user_path(@conn, :new), class: 'pure-menu-link' %>
```

How do I have to add the `class` code to resolve the problem?

Comment: Did you mean to use double quotes in the second example?

Comment: Also, please post the exact error message in the future.

Answer (score 3):

One has to use double quotes:

```
<%= link "Register", to: user_path(@conn, :new), class: "pure-menu-link" %>
```